# where I am making mistake in mainactivity?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am developing android app and I am getting error screenshot below when I have implemented network call in mainactivity.kt I want to know where I am making mistake

[image: error I am getting]

below my MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var adapter: CurrenciesAdapter? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        recycler_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        adapter = CurrenciesAdapter(this)

        recycler_main.adapter = adapter

        if (isInternetAvailable()) {
            getUsersData()
        }
    }


    private fun getUsersData() {

        showProgressBar()

        var apiInterface: CurrenciesResponse = CurrencyClient().getApiClient()!!.create(
            CurrenciesResponse::class.java
        )

        apiInterface.getCurrencies().enqueue(object : Callback <List<CurrencyResponse>> {
             override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<CurrencyResponse>>,
                    response: Response<List<CurrencyResponse>>)

             {
            hideProgressBar()
            val currencyResponse = response.body()
            adapter?.list = currencyResponse!!
        }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<CurrencyResponse>>, t: Throwable) {
            hideProgressBar()
            Log.e("error", t.localizedMessage)
        }
        })
    }
}
```

what I have done I have changed to response type from <List to CurrencyResponse but I am still getting response below whole gist code
https://gist.github.com/kyodgorbek/d0d9b3749ac64f15b4db87874cfe13e7

Comment: isn't it clear from the error ? it's wanting `Callback <CurrencyResponse>`

Comment: @a_local_nobody can you check following gist https://gist.github.com/kyodgorbek/d0d9b3749ac64f15b4db87874cfe13e7  I have done as you told me but error still occuring

Comment: You are having `<List<CurrencyResponse>>` where the required type is `<CurrencyResponse>`

Comment: @emkarachchi I am doing exactly  what you said I want toget inside CurrencyResponse quotes and  I want to show it in recyclerview if you check my adapter class I already implemented that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getCurrencies()` method in `CurrenciesResponse.class` has a return type of `CurrenciesResponse` whereas it should be `List<CurrenciesResponse>`.

You need to fix your `retrofit's service interface`.

Comment: it is  working but it is showing white screen

Comment: There are various things that could be going wrong. Either the response is failing, or the recycler view adapter is not setup properly. You need to debug your code for this. As far as your question belongs, that has been answered.

Comment: I will mark as accepted answer but can you check my xml files as well but you saved my time

Comment: Your XML files are not the problem. I believe your recyclerView adapter or the response status code or how your views are inflating might be the problem. For that you should debug your code to pinpoint where the problem is. Start with if the response is being received successfully or not.

Comment: @karon dhillon I have checked there is no error in mainactivity I think there is some problem in adapter I think